# Discord SDK/RPC with C# - what to chose?

Tags: c#, winforms, discord, discord.net

I am currently integrating Discord into the C# desktop application - more precisely, I am integrating Rich Presence. I see two ways I can implement this: with SDK (.dll) or with RPC, and I am not sure what to choose, so I need help/advice:

- during my testing I was not able to have Rich Presence buttons with SDK? Is that supported or I was doing it wrongly?
- For RPC I see, `For now, RPC is in private beta. We are not currently accepting any new developers into the program at this time.`. Would it be safe for me to integrate RPC into the application, as I made it work in the way I intended (I am trying to avoid SDK so I do not want to include .dll into app) ?
- In the documentation I see this line `For applications/games not approved, we limit you to creating 10 guilds and 10 channels. This limit is raised to virtually unlimited after approval.`. Does that mean that I have limit with the app? What is the approval process as I could not find anything in the documentation?